# Fixed points of the adjoint representation for an algebraic group

Tags: algebraic-geometry, lie-algebras, algebraic-groups

Let $G$ be a reductive affine algebraic group over $k$, and consider the adjoint action $G \xrightarrow{\text{Ad}} \text{GL}(\frak{g})$, where $\frak{g}$$=\text{Lie}(G)$ is the Lie algebra of $G$. I want to prove that if the center of $G$ is positive dimensional then $\frak{g}$ has a fixed point under the adjoint action. My attempt is to relate $Z(G)$ with $Z(G(k[\epsilon])$, this works in $GL_n$ but I can't make it work in general.